# Keras Sequential model with cRelu activation

Tags: keras, sequential

I have a problem with creating a Dense model with 3 Layers in which the activation function is cRelu.
cRelu concatenates two relu (a negative and a positive) and creates a tensor twice the size in it's output.
When trying to add another layer after it, I always get a size mismatch error

```
model  = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(N, input_dim=K, activation=crelu))
model.add(Dense(N//2, activation=crelu))
```

How do I tell the next layer to expect a 2N input and to N?

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 500 and 250 for 'dense_2/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,500], [250,83].

Comment: How exactly is your crelu implemented? I think that is the issue, it should be a layer so shape inference works.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L2690-L2713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keras doesn't expect the activation function to change the output shape. If you want to change it, you should wrap the crelu functionality in a layer and specify the corresponding output shape:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Layer

class cRelu(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(cRelu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(cRelu, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return tf.nn.crelu(x)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        """
        All axis of output_shape, except the last one,
        coincide with the input shape.
        The last one is twice the size of the corresponding input 
        as it's the axis along which the two relu get concatenated.
        """
        return (*input_shape[:-1], input_shape[-1]*2)
```

Then you can use it as follows

```py
model  = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(N, input_dim=K))
model.add(cRelu())
model.add(Dense(N//2))
model.add(cRelu())
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the returned shape in compute_output_shape method? It seems odd

Comment: Yes! and the asterisk before the first element in the returned tuple? Is it a typo?

Comment: It is not a typo at all. It's the Python unpacking operator: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: @Amirfel If you think that this answer is correct I suggest you to consider approving it, so anyone facing a similar problem can easily see that this problem can be solved with this answer. If you think the problem is not solved, please give the corresponding feedback